# Defining default parameter in lifted declaration

Tags: c++

I have a function of type `void send(int option, int key = 0)` where `key` has a default argument of `1`. Due to referencing issues with the linker I have to declare the type of `send` at the top of the file:

```cpp
void send(int option, int key);

...

void send(int option, int key = 0) {
    // Actual implementation here
}
```

I have a bunch of calls to the `send` function some with and some without a value for `key` e.g. `send(4)` and `send(2, 6)`

The problem is compiling the top line / initial function declaration:

*Attempt 1*:

```
void send(int option, int key);
```

Throws errors with function `send(4)` because it thinks it needs a key value,

*Attempt 2*:

```
void send(int option, int key = 0);
```

Throws this: `error: default argument given for parameter 2 of 'void send(int, int)' [-fpermissive]
 void send(int option, int key = 0) {`

*Attempt 3*:

```
void send(int option);
void send(int option, int key);
```

Throws `undefined reference to 'send(int)'` in one of the function bodies.

I am using *gcc version 7.2.0*. How can I define the type of a function with a default / optional parameter (preferable not with a header file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the default argument in the declaration (as you should), you must not specify it in the definition.

```
void send(int option, int key = 0);

// ...

void send(int option, int key) {
    // Actual implementation here
}
```